# When to use geometric vs. arithmetic mean? Why is the former better for percentages?

Tags: trading, calculation, statistics

While computing the average price of a stock or index over a period of time, I have the choice between using an arithmetic mean or a geometric mean. Which should I use and when?

I am reading a book on Trading Systems by Kaufman and he says:

> The geometric mean has advantages in application to economics and prices.
>   A classic example compares a tenfold rise in price from 100 to 1000 to a
>   fall to one tenth from 100 to 10. An arithmetic mean of the 2 values 10
>   and 1000 is 505, while the geometric mean gives
>
> `G = (10 × 1000)^(1/2) = 100`
>
> and shows the relative distribution of prices as a function of comparable
>   growth. Due to this property, the geometric mean is the best choice when
>   averaging ratios that can be either fractions or percentages.

I am not able to understand what he means by that last part (from "relative distribution" onward.) Could somebody please explain?

Comment: On re-reading, the explanation cited doesn't reflect reality. The math is correct, but a more realistic +/-50% is exaggeration enough. +/-20% is still zero average but -2%/yr geometric, which I suppose should be a decent number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple.  Say in 2012 you were up 50% (brilliant) but then in 2013 you were down 50% (sorry). i.e. if you started with $1000, you were up to $1500, then down to $750. You lost $250 overall.

If you were to compute the mean of the *percentages* using each method, then:

- Arithmetic mean: The average of +50% and -50% (really 150% and 50% of each period's initial value) is zero, not up or down.
- Geometric mean: `1.5 * .5 = .75`, i.e. you are down 25% over 2 years, or about 13.4% per year.

It should be clear the Geometric makes more sense in such a case.

Comment: Given the massive edits, it should be clear Joe should not answer questions on his iPhone at red lights. Thank you, Chris.

Comment: Thanks. But while calculating GM in your example, why you did not take the square root of 1.5*.5. Sorry, but can you elaborate more on your answer

Comment: First, I did. I edited as I was off a tiny bit. SQR of .75 is .866. Or the -13.4% per year. Better?

Comment: Thanks. Is there a case where using AM to compute average returns will be better than GM. Or is it always better to use GM?

Comment: AM is a misleading number. A financial celebrity is known to cite an average expected return of 12%. But the GM is more like 10%, and over the long term, it's not about a pedantic quibbling over words, but a real difference in the returns one would see.

Comment: Thank you, I will use GM from now on. When Mutual Funds quote their returns, do you know what they use? AM/GM/HM?

Answer (score 1):

JoeTaxpayer nailed it.

Here's another way to look at it: Generally, we invest in something, then might leave it there for a few years, then take it out, but don't touch it in between. 
In that case, to get the final amount X(N), we need to take the initial amount, then **multiply** by growth in the first year, then **multiply** by growth in the second year, etc.

So, for three years, we have:

X(3) = X(0) * G(1) * G(2) * G(3) = X(0) * "average annual growth" ^ 3

So, here, we see that we want the average annual growth to the power three equal to the product of the annual growth rates, thus, geometric mean:

geometric mean = (G(1) * G(2) * G(3)) ^ (1/3)

On the other hand, consider a situation where I have three investments X,Y,Z over one year. Now I have, after one year:

X(1)+Y(1)+Z(1) = X(0)*G(1,X) + Y(0)*G(1,Y) + Z(0)*G(1,Z) = ( X(0)+Y(0)+Z(0) ) * "average annual growth"

Now, in this case, if we assume X(0) = Y(0) = Z(0) = 1, i.e. I put equal amounts in each, we see that the average annual growth rate we want in this case is the arithmetic mean:

arithmetic mean = (G(1,X) + G(1,Y) + G(1,Z)) / 3

(if we had unequal amounts at the beginning, it would be a weighted average).

TL;DR:

- if we're interested in ONE investment over MANY years, we need to multiply -> use the geometric mean.
- if we're interested in MANY investments over ONE year, we need to add -> use the arithmetic mean.
- if we're interested in MANY investments over MANY years.... it gets complicated :-)

Comment: Thanks. But what is wrong with using GM for many investments in one year? It seems the choice of the average is personal preference here.

Comment: If I put 100$ into stock X, and 100$ into stock Y, and X stays at 100$, and Y goes to 144$, I made 44$ on a 200$ investment, or 22%. Now, 1.22 is the arithmetic mean of 1.00 and 1.44, while the geometric mean is 1.20.   So, to be maybe a bit more precise, the arithmetic mean is appropriate for **parallel** investments, while the geometric mean is appropriate for **successive** investments (that are re-invested).